# How to apply conditional formatting to rows?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have some requirements, I need to format rows by their efficiency. BI is now formatting by columns and has no default settings for rows. This is what it looks like now:

[image]

but i need to do like this:

[image]

I not good at DAX yet, so i don't understand how to do this. I mean how to formate values for row, for example:

1    1 0 4 5 6 10

2    0 3 0 5 2 4

3    1 3 1 4 2 1

Where "0" is min of the 1st row and "10" is max of the 1st row; In row 2 min is a "0" and "5" is a max and so on.

Can you help me? Any advice or links would be appreciated. Thank you!

I tried creating additional tables for sorting. Some manipulation of measures. But no one method sorts by rows.

Comment: Can you please add more details?

Comment: @AseelAl-Laham Yeah, sure, I tried to explain more.

Comment: I really wanted to help, but it's not possible; vote for this idea on Power BI using this link; in which if the number of votes was big enough, power bi would hopefully implement this feature. The link is:
https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=229a6a2b-f26c-4afd-b1af-8cf3cbc9810f